# system.reflection.ambiguousmatchexception error EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a strange situation. This part of code:

```
List<Order> orders = orderRepository.Query().Where(x => x.del != true).ToList();
```

Returns an error: 
`System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException- Ambiguous match found.`

What is more - without that code below, everything works fine.

How to resolve it? Why I get that error?

Order.cs:

```
public partial class Order
{
    (..)
    public virtual Country UserCountry { get; set; }
    public virtual Country CompanyCountry { get; set; }
    public virtual DeliveryType UserDeliveryType { get; set; }
    public virtual PaymentType UserPaymentType { get; set; }
    //without that virtual properties everything works fine

}
```

MyContext.cs:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .HasRequired(u => u.UserCountry)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.CountryID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);


        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .HasRequired(u => u.CompanyCountry)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.companyCountry).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);


        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .HasRequired(u => u.UserDeliveryType)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.DeliveryTypeID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .HasRequired(u => u.UserPaymentType)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.PaymentTypeID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        //and without that part of code
```

Comment: What does `orderRepository.Query()` do? Does it simply return `context.Orders`, or does it do more than that?

Comment: `.HasRequired(u => u.CompanyCountry).WithMany().HasForeignKey(u => u.companyCountry)` looks suspicious: you've got two properties that only differ in name by case, so a case-insensitive property search would result in exactly the exception you get. Do you still get the error if you rename one of those properties?

Comment: @hvd - `orderRepository.Query()` returns `context.Orders`. Thats all. Yep, I tried to rename it, but without any success - still same error.